# NotImplementedException was unhandled, but removed throw new 'NotImp..' line

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services

So a brief synopsis of what I'm trying (read: failing) to do: I'm creating a webservice that takes customers credit card information that they have entered into textboxes in my form ("UserName", "Password", "TransType", etc) and passing them on to another company's webservice that handles our credit card transactions.

```
using IntegrityWebService.SmartPaymentsService;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IntegrityWebService
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string MagData;
        //public static string transactResponse;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SmartPaymentsSoapClient transact = new SmartPaymentsSoapClient();
            transact.ProcessCreditCard(UserName, Password, TransType, CardNum, ExpDate, MagData, NameOnCard, Amount, InvNum,
                PNRef, Zip, Street, City, State, CVNum, ExtData);  


        }
```

So here is where I had the "throw new NotImplementedException();" line, but I got rid of it, and still the problem persists. Really not sure what I'm doing wrong here. It highlights both "transact" in the first two lines above. Is this something I need to declare? I'm woefully confused and indebted to anyone that gives me any shred of help here. I regret accepting this challenge from my boss, who knows I've never done any webservice/SOAP work before.

```
/*private void ProcessCreditCard(TextBox userName, TextBox password, ComboBox transType, TextBox cardNum, TextBox expDate, string magData, TextBox nameOnCard, TextBox amount, TextBox invNum, TextBox pNRef, TextBox zip, TextBox street, TextBox city, TextBox state, TextBox cVNum, TextBox extData)
    {

    }*/
}
```

Why do I still get the NotImplementedException error?

Comment: *"Why do I still get the NotImplementedException error?"* Because some line of code somewhere is throwing it, and you're executing that line. Look at the stack trace and find out where. It does seem plausible that if your web service is *not implementing* the `ProcessCreditCard` method any more, then something might be throwing a *not implemented exception* when you try to call it.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement a Interface in a non-abstract class, every function must be coded out. The compiler can not guess your intention and Interface functions are extremely likely to have return values, so it simply will write this for every single function:

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Exceptions technically count as return value. That way it can compile. But everyone calling that function will get a meaninfull information - that the writer forgot to **actually** implement that function.

SmartPaymentsSoapClient apparently implements a interface that dictates a ProcessCreditCard Function to be there. But it was never defined when writing that class.
Deleting that line in the Soap client meant that it's code can no longer compile. So what you are using is propably the laste compiled itteration.

With Exceptions we need to know the exact line it happened. As well as Type, Message and full Stacktraces (easiest way to get that is Exception.ToString())

Comment: So where do I use "Exception.ToString()"?

Comment: In this case your issues is that the new code for SmartPaymentsSoapClient will not compile. So you keep using the previous itteration that did compile.
Uncomment that line. Without it, the code can not compile (Interface function not implemented). It might be able to run empty. But if not, a return as only action should work. Make sure you are using the right compiled version: The one in Debug or Bin folder, depending on Debug or real build.

Comment: Uncomment the lines at the very bottom? Do I need to re-add "throw new NotImplementedException();" inside the private void ProcessCreditCard brackets?

Comment: Christopher, if you could, can you explain how to use Exception.ToString()? And where exactly this is going?